# Do Kafka consumers receive messages that have already been flushed (fsynched) to disk?

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer, fsync

I have read an outdated pdf on Kafka that states that consumers will receive messages that have already been committed to durable storage (disk).

However more recent search results do not clearly state such a specification.

Can anyone please confirm if modern Kafka and the consumers, receive messages that have been fsynched? Or do they receive messages that are replicated only (not implying an fsync).

Comment: How old is the pdf? The protocol hasn't drastically changed in several years

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think 2011. Here is the link:
http://notes.stephenholiday.com/Kafka.pdf

The relevant section is:
"A message is
only exposed to the consumers after it is flushed."